# Nav bar collapse not working bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to get my navigation to collapse down although it goes down but when I click the button again to go back up it does not work.

```
  <div class="menu-btn-respons-container">
          <button id="menu-btn" type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu .navbar-collapse">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon_menu hamb-mob-icon"></span>
          </button>
     </div>


<div id="main-menu" class="font-raleway">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <nav class="collapse collapsing navbar-collapse right-1024">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create CodePen or JSFiddle?